# How to remove the filename from the top of some text files

Tags: regex, perl, text, duplicates

I am trying to use fdupes in Mac OSX to remove duplicate text files from a directory. It has already removed a bunch of duplicates.

The problem I'm having now is that among the ones remaining, many are duplicates, except that in one of the files, the filename is the first line, followed by an empty line, followed by the text.

So, I'd like to find all the files that have the filename repeated at the top, and then strip this and the following blank line so that fdupes will recognize them as duplicates. This will allow me to use fdupes to parse them.

Example:

file001.txt:

```
test 123
test
```

file002.001.txt:

```
file002.001.txt

test 123
test
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but I suppose you could reach your goal easier by using command-line tools like `sed`, `diff`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's#\Q$ARGV\E$/{2}##' *.txt
```

`$ARGV` contains the file name. `$/` is your input record separator -- you may need to use `\n` or whatever your line endings are. Since `$/` contains a slash, we change the delimiter of `s///` to something else, in this case `#`. The `\Q ... \E` escape is there to make certain meta characters in your file names do not screw anything up.

The `-0777` switch makes perl read the entire file at once, so that we can match multiple lines in one regex.

The `-i` switch will do in-place edit. You may add a suffix to keep a backup, but that may not be practical when used on many files. However, I recommend you not use the `-i` switch until you are certain everything goes as you want and just print to standard output.

Comment: Ok, let me make sure I understand correctly. If my line seperator is \n, it should look like: perl -0777 -pi -e 's#\Q$ARGV\E\n{2}##' *.txt

Comment: @Zug That is correct. Remember that changes are irreversible, so try it out first.

Comment: @Zug: Except that the `$/` variabl should be set to that already so the code should work as it stands